# Python で IPv4 のサブネットマスク文字列の判定をしたい

Tags: python, network

#### 目的

dot(`.`)で区切られたIPv4のサブネットマスク文字列がサブネットマスクとして有効であることを判定したい。

#### 判定例

```
'255.128.0.0'->'1111 1111 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000' :OK
'255.64.0.0.'->'1111 1111 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000' :NG
```

#### 質問内容

下記ソースコードで機能的に満足しますが、もっとエレガントな記述方法があると思うので、ご教示をお願いしたいです。

ソースコード

```
import re


def chk(subnetmask):
    chk_string = re.compile(
        r"[0-9]{1,3}[.]{1}[0-9]{1,3}[.]{1}[0-9]{1,3}[.]{1}[0-9]{1,3}", re.A)

    if chk_string.fullmatch(subnetmask):
        mask_octet = subnetmask.split(".")
        mask_octet = list((map(int, mask_octet)))

        mask = 0
        for i, n in enumerate(mask_octet):
            mask += n*2**(8*(3-i))

        # 2進数文字列変換 接頭文字は削除
        bmask = bin(mask)
        bmask = bmask.lstrip("0b")

        # 32bit 先頭bit=1なら文字列長8bitx4oct=32のはず。
        if len(bmask) == 8*4:
            # 文字1のカウント
            count1 = bmask.count('1')
            # 32bitの1ではないはずの桁数部分を削除するために除算
            # いわゆるビットシフト
            lmask = bin(int(mask/(2**(8*4-count1))))
            lmask = lmask.lstrip("0b")
            c1 = lmask.count('1')
            # 前詰めなら同数になるはず
            if count1 == c1:
                return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import ipaddress

def chk(subnetmask):
    try:
        ipaddress.IPv4Network((0, subnetmask))
        return True
    except ipaddress.NetmaskValueError:
        return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(chk('255.128.0.0'))
    print(chk('255.64.0.0'))

#
True
False
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。NetmaskValueError例外というのがあるのですね。

Answer (score 1):

本来は標準モジュール使うほうが簡単で便利だけど, 自分で実装してみるのも演算子の勉強になったりするかもです。
標準モジュールはこちら。

- (Python HOWTO) [ipaddressモジュールの紹介](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/howto/ipaddress.html)
- [ipaddress --- IPv4/IPv6 操作ライブラリ](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/ipaddress.html)

ネットマスクは, 30種類程度ならすべて保持しておいて, どれか HITするか調べるのも手かも。

```py
allff = 0xffffffff
lst = [(~((1 <<n) -1)) &allff for n in range(2, 32)]
for msk in lst:
    pattern = f'{msk:b}'
    print(pattern)

# 出力
11111111111111111111111111111100
11111111111111111111111111111000
11111111111111111111111111110000
11111111111111111111111111100000
11111111111111111111111111000000
11111111111111111111111110000000
11111111111111111111111100000000
(略)
```